# Google maps API v3 - externally controlling radius on distanceWidget

Tags: google-maps-api-3

this seems pretty specific to ask - but there was no other alternative to the expertbase of stackoverflow!

I'm stuck in a problem where I need to control the radius of the circle by an external means such as a dropdown or a textbox.

I had a hard time doing the circle and had to copy stuff from the Twitter search example on:
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/mvcfun/twittersearch.html

Ideally, I would like to know how to bind an external even to the radiusWidget, the problem is - the sizer inside the radiusWidget seems a private entity.

It would be awesome if someone could hit me in the face with a bang!

Thx

Comment: From a different post I could relate to, the following is similar to what I tend to achieve:

[example link](http://jsfiddle.net/T7VUC/embedded/result/)

And also, the distanceWidget is available here:

[distanceWidget source](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-samples-v3/source/browse/trunk/talks/io2011/map-usability/distancewidget.js?spec=svn265&r=265)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

distanceWidget.set('distance', XXX) should work. If you read the MVC article you can see how the binding is bi-directional.

Comment: Ah yes - forgot! hmm .. I'd tried that earlier via console in firebug, it had worked, but the sizer icon would stay in its old position. So looked a little weird. Any ideas on how to move that? :(

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the source of the Twitter example by downloading it to your computer, as you likely already did. When you have the source you can adapt it to your purposes as you like. The software usage rights (terms of usage, license, etc), if they are any, have to be respected of course.

In the case of the `RadiusWidget` you would just do:

```
function RadiusWidget(opt_distance) {
   // ...
  this.sizer = this.addSizer_(); // sizer is now accessible in RadiusWidget
}

RadiusWidget.prototype.addSizer_ = function() {
   var sizer = ... 
   // ...
   return sizer;
}
```